# String array - needless synchronization?

Tags: java, multithreading, chronicle

I'm studying ChronicleHFT libraries. I found a class `StringInterner` posted below

```
public class StringInterner {
    @NotNull
    protected final String[] interner;
    protected final int mask;
    protected final int shift;
    protected boolean toggle = false;

    public StringInterner(int capacity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        int n = Maths.nextPower2(capacity, 128);
        this.shift = Maths.intLog2((long)n);
        this.interner = new String[n];
        this.mask = n - 1;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String intern(@Nullable CharSequence cs) {
        if (cs == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (cs.length() > this.interner.length) {
            return cs.toString();
        } else {
            int hash = Maths.hash32(cs);
            int h = hash & this.mask;
            String s = this.interner[h];
            if (StringUtils.isEqual(cs, s)) {
                return s;
            } else {
                int h2 = hash >> this.shift & this.mask;
                String s2 = this.interner[h2];
                if (StringUtils.isEqual(cs, s2)) {
                    return s2;
                } else {
                    String s3 = cs.toString();
                    this.interner[s != null && (s2 == null || !this.toggle()) ? h2 : h] = s3;
                    return s3;
                }
            }
```

I found yt video from Peter Lawrey on which he explains (or to be more precise - he just says) that this class is thread safe and doesn't need any additional synchronization to work in multithreaded environment. Video yt link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNSD6AUG5a0&t=1200

My question is why this class doesn't need any sync?

1. How about visibility - if one thread put something into interner[n], does another threads are guaranteed to see it?
2. What happens in case, when scheduler yields a thread in the middle of method? Does it lead to put same value in same index twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Javadoc for StringInterner](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Core/blob/chronicle-core-2.20.10/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/core/pool/StringInterner.java) explains that it's not technically thread-safe:

> StringInterner only guarantees it will behave in a correct manner. When you ask it for a String for a given input, it must return a String which matches the toString() of that CharSequence.
>
> It doesn't guarantee that all threads see the same data, nor that multiple threads will return the same String object for the same string. It is designed to be a best-effort basis so it can be as lightweight as possible.
>
> So while technically not thread safe, it doesn't prevent it operating correctly when used from multiple threads, but it is faster than added explicit locking or thread safety. NOTE: It does rely on String being thread safe, something which was guarenteed from Java 5.0 onwards.

Incidentally, I'm curious about the claim that `String` was not thread-safe prior to Java 5; I'd love to see a citation.

Comment: Thread-safe and guaranteed thread-safe don't mean the same thing.  It could be that this is just a change in specification ... and that (all / most / typical / whatever) string implementations were actually thread-safe prior to Java 5 anyway.

Comment: The other thing ... should we be trusting javadoc that can't spell the word guarantee ? :-)

Comment: JSR 133 improved the memory model. http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html and this was included in J2SE Tiger. https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133 which was Java 5.0 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_5.0

Comment: Alexey Shipilev recommended not to use String.intern() and turn away from the concept of interning towards deduplication in his string catechism. Implementing a deduplicator is easy. Implementing an interner is very hard! More information about that idea on https://shipilev.net/talks/joker-Oct2014-string-catechism.pdf#Outline0.7